# matplotlib: change axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an array of measurements m, taken every minute. I plot these measurements against time by simply saying

```
import pylab as pl
pl.plot(range(len(m)), m)
```

this gives me minutes on the x-axis (just because I have measurements in minutes and range(len(m)) gives me integers). How do I quickly change the labeling of the x-axis into hours? I basically need to take the labeling mod 60, but I would like to have only integer hour values.

So in short I want to relabel every multiple of 60 on the x-axis.

Comment: I am not certain I understand what you are asking for.  Do you only want a tick every 60 minutes? or do you want every multiple of 60 to be labeled differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry rather than xlabels you need to create an axis and us ax.set_xticklabels:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
fig = figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)


def mk_labels(vals):
    labels = []
    for i in vals:
        if i % 60 == 0:
            labels.append("Some new special label")
        else:
            labels.append(i)


 ax.set_xticklabels(mk_labels(range(len(m))))
 ax.plot(range(len(m)), m)
```

or simply:

```
 ax.set_xticklabels(["{0}h".format(i) if i % 60 == 0 else i for i in range(len(m))])
```

Either of these methods will work the first one may be easier if you need more complicated formatting.

Answer (score 2):

```
pylab.plot(data) # pylab will automatically add an x-axis from 0 to len(data) - 1

# first argument is when ticks should appear on the x-axis
# the second argument is what the label for each tick should be
# same as -> pylab.xticks([0, 60, 120...], [0, 1, 2...])
pylab.xticks(range(0, len(data), 60), range(len(data)/60))

# let the reader know the units
pylab.xlabel("hours")
```

Comment: I think you want `range(len(data)/60+1)` for the second argument of xticks. Other than that, this is a very simple, clean explination.

Comment: @eryksun can you explain your comment a bit more? If data is length 100, then range(len(data)/60) is [0], but for the plot it it should be [0,1].

Comment: @eryskun I get it now. Also I think `range((len(data)+59)/60)` produces the correct labels.